# Mongodb Logs flood

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am starting to use Mongodb to storage my data, and when I started the service, I am getting a log flood, I want to turn off this log saves, I don't mind if I do not have any kind of logs, it is development environment and need to do that, because my log file is growing more than 30gb by 2 or 3 days.

I've tried to change quiet to true as below, but with no success.

```
root@master:~# cat /etc/mongod.conf 
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
journal:
enabled: true
# engine:
# mmapv1:
# wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
verbosity: 0
destination: file
logAppend: true

###### HERE ######
quiet: true

path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
# path: /dev/null
component:
accessControl:
verbosity: 1
command:
verbosity: 1
```

Any idea how to get a clean logs?? could be a logs with nothing.

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some examples of the excessive log entries you are trying to suppress as well as your versions of MongoDB and O/S? The `quiet` config option should reduce logging for connection and replication events, but does not affect other diagnostic logging like slow queries. You probably don't want to completely ignore logs as there may be some useful information for development. There are different options depending on your MongoDB & O/S versions.

Comment: It is too big, I take some lines and paste on pastebin, follow the link: https://pastebin.com/uXRsFm58

Comment: Thanks .. just needed some examples of the log lines. The "end connection" messages should be suppressed with `quiet`; I believe the COMMAND messages are appearing because you have set command verbosity to 1 in your config. Try commenting out or removing your `verbosity` options. What are your specific versions of MongoDB server and O/S?

Comment: Thank you for your help, distmod: debian92 O/S, and mongodb: 4.0.5